# Unable to connect to world when it was working before

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am using a Samsung tablet, and my friend uses Windows 10. Both of us use Bedrock edition. We are usually able to connect to each other's worlds but when I try to join her world now it says "unable to connect to world" every single time.

What are some troubleshooting steps I can take to connect our devices to the same world again?